# /Add-Driver not getting recognized as valid command

Tags: iot, azure-iot-hub, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to add few Intel LAN and Chipset drivers to an existing WIndows IoT core ffu image file. I mounted the ffu and trying to add drivers using /Add-Driver command, but it is not getting recognized.

I have the latest version of DISM and I tried accesing the Dism file from **`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment`** and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\DISM as well but no luck. Can someone help me out with this issue?

1. Is there a way to install .exe files while creating ffu base image itself? I could not extract inf file for the chipset exe

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to install .exe files while creating ffu base image itself. If you want to add a custom or third-party driver to Windows IoT Core ffu image, you need to build the custom ffu image with bsp. Please refer to this document about how to [add a driver to an image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/iot/add-a-driver-to-an-image). In addition,please note that, if your device is ARM, please contact the supplier of the peripheral to get the driver files. Here is a [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/peripheraldrivers) as reference about how to add third-party drivers (usb) for peripheral devices such as USB Mobile broadband modems, printers, scanners etc.